# Using XYPieChart inside Collection View cells - charts not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My goal is to include an [XYPieChart](https://github.com/xyfeng/XYPieChart) in each of my subclassed `UICollectionViewCells` called `PictureCollectionCell`. The actual pie chart view (called `pieChart`) is hooked up to the prototype cell in Storyboard.

Presently, I set `PictureCollectionCell` to be the delegate for both the data source and delegate, and in the cell's `initWithCoder` does the following:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    NSLog(@"Called?");
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self){
        // Initialization code
        [self.pieChart setDataSource:self];
        [self.pieChart setDelegate:self];

        //Note: the actual pie slices are set inside the cells
        [self.pieChart reloadData];
    }
    return self;
}
```

(I also implemented the XYChart **delegate** and **datasource** methods's inside `PictureCollectionCell`, which I omitted pasting here.)

Inside my `CollectionViewController`, I have the following:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PictureCollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSNumber *sliceOne = [NSNumber numberWithInt:33];
    NSNumber *sliceTwo = [NSNumber numberWithInt:33];
    cell.slices = @[sliceOne, sliceTwo];
    [cell.pieChart reloadData];

    return cell;
}
```

However, my problem is that none of the pie charts in the cells are actually showing, and I also see that the delegate methods are not being called. What am I doing incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: is it safe to assume you are using CorePlot? You never actually said so.

Comment: Thanks RobP - it is actually this: https://github.com/xyfeng/XYPieChart. It appears that none of the dependencies mention CorePlot. Will update the question to include link.

Comment: gotcha. Just to eliminate simple things first, if you stop in the debugger can you check that in initWithCoder self.pieChart might be null? I would expect it to be null until ViewDidLoad...

Comment: Yes! This was very helpful debugging suggestion - thanks. This coupled with the answer below solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the following to the method awakeFromNib:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code
    [self.pieChart setDataSource:self];
    [self.pieChart setDelegate:self];

    //Note: the actual pie slices are set inside the cells
    [self.pieChart reloadData];
}
```

The reason is that in initWithCoder the outlets are not wired yet, so probably pieChart is nil at that point;

Comment: Matias, obviously we were on the same page here, but out of curiosity is there any reason it is better or worse in awakeFromNib vs. viewDidLoad? I can't really think of any...

Comment: Rob, UITableViewCell/UICollectionViewCell subclasses don't have viewDidLoad. That's for UIViewController subclasses.